# How to properly have one-to-one relation in MongoDB without any cons?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project and have these two MongoDB collections, team (holding the details of teams) and payment (holding the payment of the teams) (strictly 1-1 relationship).

```
Payment Schema
{
    ...
    team: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team', unique: true },
    ...
}
```

For Team, I have two alternatives:

```
Team1 Schema
{
    user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}
```

...

```
Team2 Schema
{
    user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    payment: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Payment', unique: true }
}
```

**NEED:** I have a component "My Teams" where I need to show logged-in user's all teams and his payment status (yes/no).

**ISSUE WITH Team1 Schema:** Since I do not have reference to Payment so I need to make another call to backend with team's _id to get Payment object for every team. If a user has 10 teams then it will be 11 backend calls (1 for teams, next 10 for their payment statuses).

**ISSUE WITH Team2 Schema:** Since I now have Payment _id inside the Team2 Schema so I can simply check if that field exist or not to determine if it's paid or not. But now the issue is, when a payment is made, I need to update both of Collections and need to use Transactions (to rollback in case any fails) which increases complexity and is also not support unless I have replica sets set upped.

Can you please help me figuring out this the best way possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to have team_id in payment schema (which you already have).

You neither need user_id nor payment_id in team schema to get payments with team.
You could just have an aggregate query with lookup on the payments table to get the team along with payment.

So, considering you have an ID of teams and you need the teams data along with the payments data, you could write an aggregation query, something like this,

```
             Team.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { _id: { $in: list_of_user_ids } } // this will get the teams which match the array of ids
            },
            {
                $lookup: // this will search data from a different collection
                {
                    from: 'payments', // the collection to search from
                    localField: '_id', // the matching field in the team collection
                    foreignField: 'team', // matching field in the payment colection
                    as: 'payment' the name you want to give to the resulting payment object
                }
            }
           ])
```

**Edit 1:** 
The lookup I've written does exactly what you need. Just that I assumed you had an array of user Ids. If you have a single user ID, just change the match operation to  what you've written

```
           $match: { user_id:  currently_loggedin_userId }
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach but I am still stuck. You can ignore the user_id in Team schema, it is kind of mandatory to reference currently logged-in user. I am kind of confused with what `$match: { _id: { $in: list_of_user_ids } }` is doing. From my understanding, I need to first do `$match: { user_id: currently_loggedin_userId }` to get only those teams which are related to currently logged in userId. Then I will have to get payments objects for each of those teams (if any exist), so it is LEFT OUTER JOIN in MySQL sense. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much @Visrozar . This worked perfectly fine. I missed the point that I can search non-_id elements in the referenced collections using $lookup.

Comment: I only had to do: `$match: { user_id:  ObjectId(currently_loggedin_userId) }` due to https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399